# Visual Studio 2010: how to force ASP.NET website to use x86 instead of "Any CPU"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, sharepoint-2010

When using SharePoint DLLs (which are x86 only) from a non-ASP.NET app, you can set the "Platform target" to x86 (instead of "Any CPU") so both Visual Studio 2010 and the app load the SharePoint assemblies fine.

However, when developing ASP.NET applications on an x64 development system, you get this dreaded error message when building the web-site:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Search' or one
>   of its dependencies. An attempt was
>   made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

This is because ASP.NET by default is "Any CPU" when building in Visual Studio 2010.

How can I change that?

I tried the property pages for the web-site, the web.config, but to no avail.

Note: this is for the *development system*. I know that for the *server system*, I can change the application pool to force loading of 32-bit x86 by setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to "True" in the "Application Pool Defaults".

Comment: Actually, SharePoint 2010 (which is one of you tags) is x64 only. SharePoint 2007 had both x86 and x64 versions, although I think the x86 was much more common.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Something fishy is going on, as I had to mark the App Pool for my ASP.NET app as 32-bit only, otherwise it would not load at all. I will get back on this, but it might be friday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set custom compiler option on web.config on the `<compilers>`

```
compilerOptions="/platform:string"
```

where string can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4(v=VS.100).aspx but I still get the same error. The `compiler` portion is now this: `<compiler compilerOptions="/platform:x86" language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">`

Comment: @Jeroen the compilerOptions is works, for example try setting the /D:MYDEBUG , or define something other and its work. And I think that if there is not clear option to define the x86, the compiler Option is the last one. Now if not work, what can I say....?

Comment: After a reinstall of the machine, it now works :) 
I approved your answer because it basically tells you how to do this.