# Change Web Site to use x86 platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

**The Problem:**

I have inherrited a solution that has 4 pieces in it.  Two of those pieces are C# projects used for database stuff.  Easy enough there.  The other two pieces are Web Sites.  Right now, everything is set in the Configuration Manager to use AnyCpu.  What I need to do is change the websites to x86 for this specific reason:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\<My Company>\<My Application>", false);
```

Note:  It isn't literally My Company inside the <> marks.  I just mean the name of my company.

After doing some research, I learned the following:

1. .NET app compiled for "x86":

   - Always 32-bit
   - On 32-bit platforms, accesses 32-bit registry
   - On 64-bit platforms, accesses 32-bit registry (inside Wow6432Node)
2. .NET app compiled for "x64":

   - Always 64 bit
   - On 32-bit platforms, won't run
   - On 64-bit platforms, accesses 64-bit registry (not inside Wow6432Node)
3. .NET app compiled for "AnyCpu"

   - Either 32 or 64 bit depending on platform
   - On 32-bit platforms, accesses 32-bit registry
   - On 64-bit platforms, accesses 64-bit registry (not inside Wow6432Node)

So, what I NEED is to be able to compile for x86, as the application is installed as 32-bit and will show up inside the Wow6432Node folder on 64-bit OS's.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to change a Web Site's target platform after it was initially set up?

**What I've tried:**

1. Inside VS 2010, go to Build --> Configuration Manager.
2. Under the Active solution platform:  Select "New..."
3. Add in the x86 platform.
4. Attempt to change my two Web Sites to x86.

Step 4 is where it fails.  x86 is not an option.  It shows up for my two C# projects just fine.  Is this possible to change?

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In my Configuration Manager, when I create a new Solution Platform I get a checkbox to automatically create new project platforms. Do you get that option?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried it both checked and unchecked.  It didn't work for me either way.

Comment: Also, on the web project "Build" property page, there's a dropdown to select "Platform Target". Can you modify that?

Comment: I do not have a "Platform Target" if I go to the Build tab by right-clicking the Web Site and selecting Property Page.  I have Target Framework, and I've got that set to .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: I have Target Framework on the Application tab of the project properties. The build tab is the one below that.

Comment: You probably have an ASP.NET Web Application project.  The type of project I'm talking about is an ASP.NET Web Site.  From what I can tell, VS will only allow you to create one on an already existing solution with something in it.  You would right-click the solution in the Solution Explorer, and select Add --> New Web Site.  The option will then be there.

Comment: Apologies - you are correct. I don't appear to have the option to create a "Web Site" rather than "Web Application" project, possibly due to how I installed VS2010.

Comment: I have resolved the larger problem of installing my application on Server 2003 R2 64-bit, but I'm still unaware if this is possible, so I'll leave it up in hopes that a resolution exists.

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656468/visual-studio-2010-how-to-force-asp-net-website-to-use-x86-instead-of-any-cpu

Answer (score 1):

Dave White is right in the comments, there is an answer for this in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656769/1037864

(The answer is to set compilerOptions="/platform:x86" on the compiler element in web.config)