# Change Web Site to use x86 platform, VS2019, Visual Studio 2019

Tags: x86, web-config, visual-studio-2019

My question is similar to these two:

- [Change Web Site to use x86 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920087/change-web-site-to-use-x86-platform)
- [Visual Studio 2010: how to force ASP.NET website to use x86 instead of "Any CPU"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656468/visual-studio-2010-how-to-force-asp-net-website-to-use-x86-instead-of-any-cpu/5656769#5656769)

The difference is I'm using Visual Studio 2019.  The [answer provided in the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656769/2623259) has a link that no longer works.  The text of that answer says to edit the `<compilers>` tag in Web.config, but my Web.config doesn't have that tag, and I don't know where it goes or whether Microsoft has renamed it.  What's the way to force a **VS2019** web site to run as x86?  Thank you.

Comment: This a ASP.NET (classic) site, right? I think you need to compile the site using x86 as described in the first link and configure your IIS application pool associated with your ASP.NET Web Forms application. Set the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" property to "True" in the application pool's Advanced Settings.